# Android Studio 3.4.1, Kotlin "unresolved reference: mutableListOf"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am building an AAR with Kotlin in Android Studio 3.4.1, and I get the dreaded "unresolved reference" error when I try to use mutableListOf.

```
 val myBuffer: mutableListOf<Byte>()
```

I updated Kotlin to the latest version at the time of writing
[image]

In build.gradle, the Kotlin version is also consistently defined.
[image: kotlinversion]

In the module build.gradle, the following plugins are used:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

I understood from what I read, that the Kotlin language plugin, including collection classes, should be automatically included in Android Studio.  In any case, I'm using other Kotlin classes, e.g. ByteArray, without a problem.

Following advice that I found online, I cleaned and re-built, also selected File | Invalidate Caches/Restart and re-built.  It did not work; the reference is still unresolved.

The Kotlin documentation doesn't say that this function is deprecated, which was another possible cause that I found.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have the Kotlin stdlib in your dependencies? `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: Yes, it was automatically added in the module build.gradle dependencies.

Comment: classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" is this added in the dependencies of build.gradle  at project level

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have made some typo error: use `=` and not `:`:

```
 val myBuffer = mutableListOf<Byte>()
```

or specify type explicitly:

```
 val myBuffer: MutableList<Byte> = mutableListOf<>()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer!   Although it is a typo, I will leave this question, because some other Kotlin newbie might make the same mistake.  The error message was not intuitive for this typo :-)  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unresolved reference of `mutableListOf` or `MutableList` please try to implement this dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:$kotlin_version'
```

Answer (score 0):

lates version:

```
val myBuffer: MutableList<Byte> = mutableListOf()
```

mutableListOf <del><></del> ()