# Unresolved reference: mutableListOf ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.31"

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use a mutableListOf but I am getting an unresolved reference, I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56887331/android-studio-3-4-1-kotlin-unresolved-reference-mutablelistof) but that isn't the problem. I have looked over my gradle configuration files and can't seem to figure out what the issue is. below are config files and then the MainActivity.kt file, hopefully someone can point out the issue - I don't believe it is a simple typo at this point.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.31"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta06"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the project gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.veii.touchlessblev2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Here is the entire MainActivity

```
package com.veii.touchlessblev2

import android.app.Activity
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE
import android.content.pm.PackageManager

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

private const val ENABLE_BLUETOOTH_REQUEST_CODE = 1
private const val LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter by lazy {
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothManager.adapter
    }

    private val bleScanner by lazy {
        bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner
    }

    private val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
        .build()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }
//this is where I get Unresolved reference: mutableListOf
    val scanResults = mutableListOf<ScanResult>()


    private fun Context.hasPermission(permissionType: String): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionType) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun Activity.requestPermission(permission: String, requestCode: Int) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(permission), requestCode)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it `mutableListOf` that is unresolved or `ScanResult ` ?

Comment: mutableListOf  is ScanResult is no problem, I even tried mutableListOf <int> just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by updating Kotlin selecting "Tools" -> "Kotlin" -> "Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates" and updating the latest version which is 1.4.32.

The version of Android Studio I am using is 4.2 Beta 6

This is a great fix, I would like to know what the issue was but couldn't find anything wrong in the Gradle configuration and there was not a typo but I will take it for now.

Comment: I have the same problem. It compiles fine, but the IDE insists that there is an error and displays red text. I followed your example, but the latest version (Aug '21) displays 1.4.21-release-Studio4.0.1 on the Stable channel.
Still red.

Answer (score -2):

I had similar kind of issue where the compiler was showing unresolved reference issue but application was building successfully.

Steps to follow are -

1. Clear the cache
2. Rebuild the app

Note for Android Studio users: The path to the caches location is located under Google instead of Jetbrains. For example:
~/Library/Caches/Google/ on macOS

reference - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39776#focus=Comments-27-4860139.0-0